# Python testing - mock module at init

Tags: python, mongodb, unit-testing, module, mocking

I have a simple module connecting to a db (e.g. Mongo) at startup time and a method called at runtime to fetch data.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb://<redacted>")

db = client.mydb
collection = db.mycollection

def fetch():
    return collection.find()
```

I have tried everything to stub the `pymongo.MongoClient` call so that I can test it inside my `fetch` method. I am avoiding using a `Class` and init for this project.

My test looks like this:

```
import unittest
from mock import MagicMock, patch
from mymongo import fetch

class TestMongo(unittest.TestCase):


   @patch('mongo.MongoClient')
    def test_fetch(self, mocked_mongo):
       # tried variations of below, nothing works:
       mocked_mongo.return_value = 'STUB'
       mock.__getitem__.side_effect = lambda name: 'STUB'

       fetch()
```

I am using unittest and mock.

Seems fine if I move the connection to inside my method but that will make it connect everytime. I have tried variations of `importing` and `patching` but nothing works.

Is this possible? It appears as though it executes the init before I can inject my stub dependency.

Comment: You can't easily mock code at a top-level of a module. The solution is to *not put code at the top level of a module*. Move things into a function instead.

Comment: The moment `from mymongo import fetch` is executed, **so is the top-level code**. At this point the `client` object is created and you are too late to patch it. This happens for the first import, not every import.

Comment: thanks @MartijnPieters, is it not possible at all then? Will it not create many many unnecessary mongo connections?

Comment: You can do it, but not elegantly or easily. You'd have to a) make sure the module is not imported (deleting it from `sys.modules`), b) patch `pymongo. MongoClient`, and c) only after patching, import the module under test. But if *any other code* already imported that module you created a connection already, making it error prone in a test setup.

Comment: You can have your function cache the connection, creating just one connection then re-using that one connection each time it is called.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It could cache but i really dont want test code to cause my to write different live code. If i can do it via deleting from `sys.modules` (as you suggest above) I think i would be happier. Is there any library which exists which can help with that? (i.e. replacing dependencies in sys.modules)?

Comment: You *really* don't want to do that. There are many other issues with module imports having side effects. Just don't do it, refactor the code now.

Comment: Thats a real shame was hoping there was something like Nodes proxyquire which can help me here (super easy drop in). Appreciate the help @MartijnPieters

Comment: Related: [Mock function called on import](//stackoverflow.com/q/22616934)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Isolating unit tests in python](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/233201)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the answer thanks to help from @Martijn.

Due to dynamic importing my module stays the same, executing the setup at the top-level but now my test is as such:

```
@patch('pymongo.MongoClient', return_value=myStubObject)
def test_fetch(self, mock_dont_call):
    from mymongo import fetch

    fetch()
```

I had to have every test import the dependency it needs, but seems worth it to keep the application code as is.

Now the module in cache is the one with my stubs inside. I can now mock responses, spy on arguments etc (all from `myStubObject`). 
Hope that helps.